# ServletFileUpload.parseRequest() returning an empty list for MockMultipartHttpServletRequest

Tags: java, unit-testing, file-upload, mocking

Having looked at some of the existing answers for this topic, I still can't figure out what I might be doing wrong...

I've got the following request declaration in my Unit test:

```
final MockMultipartHttpServletRequest mockRequest = new MockMultipartHttpServletRequest();
    mockRequest.setMethod("POST");
    mockRequest.setContentType(contentType);
    mockRequest.setRequestURI("/upload");
    mockRequest.addParameter("test_param", "test_value");
    mockRequest.addFile(new MockMultipartFile("file1", "test_upload1.txt", "text/plain", "fileContent1".getBytes()));
    mockRequest.addFile(new MockMultipartFile("file2", "test_upload2.txt", "text/plain", "fileContent2".getBytes()));
    mockRequest.setContent("dummyContent".getBytes());
```

Which I then use another class to process:

```
public void processServletRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {

if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {

    final FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    final ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    List<FileItem> items = null;

    try {
      items = upload.parseRequest(request);
    } catch (final FileUploadException e) {
        this.logger.error("Could not upload document", e);
        return;
    }

}
```

}

But upload.parseRequest(request) always return an empty list.

There's nothing else between those two places that could read the input stream of the request (no calls to getParameter() or anything like that).

Can't see if the issue is with the unit test and the mock request, or the processing... Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT: Ok, manual testing seems to be successful, which means I expect the servlet is working ok and the problem lies in the way I'm building up the mock request - however, comparing it to other samples I've seen here and there, I can't really see what's wrong. The fact that the isMultipartContent() test succeeds also tells me I'm not doing it *completely* wrong...

Maybe there's something else I should be using to build up a dummy request, rather than this Spring helper class?

EDIT2: Well, I gave up and decided to build up the content of my request manually, adding parameters and file metadata by building up a StringBuilder. Will leave this open if someone can figure out what I was doing wrong before, but at least my test is functional now.

EDIT3: Adding code snippet from recent answer as asked in comment.

```
public void createMultipartFormDataRequest(MockHttpServletRequest request, String resourceName, String partName) throws IOException {

  // Load resource being uploaded
  byte[] fileContent =      FileCopyUtils.copyToByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream(resourceName));

  // Create part & entity from resource
  Part[] parts = new Part[] { new FilePart(partName, new ByteArrayPartSource(resourceName, fileContent)) };
  MultipartRequestEntity multipartRequestEntity = new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, new PostMethod().getParams());

  // Serialize request body
  ByteArrayOutputStream requestContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  multipartRequestEntity.writeRequest(requestContent);

  // Set request body to HTTP servlet request
  request.setContent(requestContent.toByteArray());

  // Set content type to HTTP servlet request (important, includes Mime boundary string)
  request.setContentType(multipartRequestEntity.getContentType());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue...the following approach worked for me.

http://devnotesblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/17/mocking-a-multipartform-data-http-request-in-a-unit-test/

Comment: Do you reckon you could edit the relevant details into your answer instead of just providing a link? If that blog gets taken down, this answer will cease to be helpful.

Comment: I've done that in my original post - couldn't edit Srinivas' answer.